# Best way to share AIDL and Parcelable files between client and server

Tags: android, service, aidl

Android AIDL services requires a copy of *.aidl and any implementation of Parcelable to exist on the remote client as well as the server. Apart from telling people to copy and paste these files from my server code, is there a better way to make this easier for client developers?

Comment: have you tried adding them in a java library perhaps ? That way they can just include the library instead of actual files

Answer (score 0):

Create an Android [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) which is shared between the client and server apps.